# Python hex bit flipping ascii

Tags: python, endianness

The following statement is from a documentation I'm following.

```
“7c bd 9c 91” 2442968444(919cbd7c hex)usec = 2442.9sec
```

If you assume:

1. 7c -> a
2. bd -> b
3. 9c -> c
4. 91 -> d

Then its easy to see how they got `919cbd7c` simply by flipping it `abcd` to `dcba`.

What I don't understand is why they aren't filliping the actual bits.

That is to say I expect `19c9dbc7` rather than `919cbd7c`.

Is there a way to convert the original string to what they expect?

EG: convert `7cbd9c91` to `919cbd7c`?

I know that I can split the string in twos and reverse the order. But is there a way python is aware of this and can decode it automatically?

Here is the [documentation](http://velodynelidar.com/docs/manuals/63-9113%20HDL-32E%20manual_Rev%20H_Sept.pdf). The part in question is on the 2nd line of page 22.

Comment: Do you simply want a way to convert the python string `'919cbd7c'` to `'19c9dbc7'`?

Comment: @Shawn: I edited my answer.

Comment: Are you actually dealing with a string `"7cbd9c91"`, or are you getting the four bytes `b"\x7c\xbd\x9c\x91"`. The latter is just a standard little-endian 32 bit number, and can be passed directly to `struct.unpack` (with the format `"<L"`).

Comment: @Blckknght. I actually get the latter. Mind redoing your comment as an answer so its formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to put too much thought into it. The hex pairs you're seeing are actually single bytes, and the order of the bits within the bytes is unambiguous. It's only the byte-order of the higher-level  multi-byte integer that can go more than one way. Fortunately, byte-order swapping is very easy, since computers have to do it all the time (network byte order is big-endian, but most PCs these days are little-endian internally).

In Python, just pass the raw bytestring you're getting (which would be `b"\x7c\xbd\x9c\x91"` for the example data shown in the documentation) to `struct.unpack` with an appropriate format parameter. Since the documentation says it's a little endian 4-byte number, use `"<L"` as the format code to specify a "little-endian unsigned long integer":

```
>>> bytestring = b"\x7c\xbd\x9c\x91" # from wherever
>>> struct.unpack("<L", bytestring)
(2442968444,)
```

Comment: How would you do it if the string was `b'\xff\xee'`. Right now, Im getting an error where it says unpack requires len 4

Comment: Basically, I want a function that given `b"\x7c\xbd\x9c\x91"` or `b"\x7c\xbd"` or `b"\x7c"` returns the int value. I understand that the last one is just itself.

Comment: I don't think such a function exists already, since generally when you're dealing with binary values, the exact size matters. You could pretty easily write your own though, using `struct.unpack` and different format parameters for the different lengths of bytestring.